# Get the route name in a Symfony service

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, symfony4, symfony-routing

Im try to get the name of the current route in a Symfony 4 service.

**routes.yaml**

```
test-route:
    path: /test
    controller: App\Controller\Test::test
```

**service**

```
class Myservice {

    private $u;

    public function __construct(Utilities $u){

        $this->u = $u;

        $route = getRouteSomehow(); // should return "test-route"
    }
}
```

I found this piece of code to grab the route:

```
$requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('_route');
```

..but not sure where/how/what to inject to be able to use it.

Perhaps there's a simpler was as well.

Comment: Inject the [request stack](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack) service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use symfony4, and autowire (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html), you can inject request_stack service as following:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class Myservice {

    private $u;

    public function __construct(Utilities $u, RequestStack $requestStack) {

        $this->u = $u;

        $route = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('_route');
    }
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that this will not work.  Right idea.  Wrong implementation.

Comment: this worked for me. why wrong implementation?