# Symfony 5 Route name in Controller

Tags: symfony, symfony5

How do I obtain the name of the current route in the controller in Symfony 5?
When I try this I get NULL:

```
$this->Request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$route = $this->Request->attributes->get('_route');

var_dump($route);
```

Comment: If you do this, you create a new request instance populated only with PHP superglobals ($_GET, $_POST, etc.). This in done in the public/index.php. During the process of the request, it is populated by the framework with several informations like the route name. You will have to try a way to retrive this request instance depending on your context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not recommended to create request inside your controller.
Preferred way of obtaining already created Request is DI and autowiring:

```
// src/Controller/BlogController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog", name="blog_list")
     */
    public function list(Request $request)
    {
        $routeName = $request->attributes->get('_route');
        $routeParameters = $request->attributes->get('_route_params');

        var_dump($routeName);
    }
}
```

This request is processed by Symfony HttpKernel and filled with additional information.

More info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#getting-the-route-name-and-parameters

How did it get there: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/b2609c4bae69ca383b97cb520da2ed9be1c48449/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php#L217

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211606/get-the-route-name-in-a-symfony-service):

Just add RequestStack as a function parameter and call `RequestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('_route');`

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

public function yourCalledFunction(Utilities $u, RequestStack $requestStack) {

    $route = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('_route');
}
```

Comment: Almost but for a controller action you would just use the request object that is injected directly into the controller action.  The request stack is used for other non-controller services and would only be injected into the constructor.

Comment: i tried this solution on my project and it worked on a controller action with annotated Route.

Comment: Yes it works but it not needed.  A controller action will always be injected with the current route as long as you typehint against Request.  Using the stack for controllers is just misleading what is obviously a newbie developer.

Comment: By the way, if you think the question was answered by an answer in another question then the recommended approach is to just provide a link in the comment section.